# Mapping nearest values from two pandas dataframes (latitude and longitude)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-science

How to map closed values from two dataframes:

I've two dataframes in below format and looking to map values based on o_lat,o_long from data1 and near_lat,near_lon:

```html
data1 ={'lat': [-0.659901, -0.659786, -0.659821], 
       'long':[2.530561, 2.530797, 2.530587], 
       'd':[0.4202, 1.0957, 0.6309],
      'o_lat':[-37.8095,-37.8030,-37.8050],
      'o_long':[145.0000,145.0077,145.0024]}
```

Where lat,long is coordinates of destination, d is the distance between origin and destination, o_lat,o_long is the coordinates of origin.

```html
data2={'nearest_warehouse': ['Nickolson','Thompson','Bakers'], 
      'lat':[-37.8185,-37.8126,-37.8099],
      'lon':[144.9695,144.9470,144.9952]}
```

I want to produce another column in data1 which locates nearest_warehouse in the following format based on closed value:

```html
result={'lat': [-0.659901, -0.659786, -0.659821], 
       'long':[2.530561, 2.530797, 2.530587], 
       'd':[0.4202, 1.0957, 0.6309],
      'o_lat':[-37.8095,-37.8030,-37.8050],
      'o_long':[145.0000,145.0077,145.0024],
        'nearest_warehouse':['Bakers','Thompson','Nickolson']}
```

I've tried following code:

```
lat_diff=[]
long_diff=[]
min_distance=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    lat_diff.append(float(warehouse.near_lat[i])-lat_long_d.o_lat[0])
for j in range(0,3):
    long_diff.append(float(warehouse.near_lon[j])-lat_long_d.o_long[0])
        long_diff.append(float(warehouse.near_lon[j])-lat_long_d.o_long[0])
min_distance=[min(lat_diff),min(long_diff)]
min_distance
```

Which gives the following result which is the minimum value of the difference between latitude and longitude for o_lat=-37.8095 and o_lang=145.0000:
[-0.00897867136701791, -0.05300973586690816].

I feel the approach is not viable to map close values over a large dataset.

Looking for a better approach in this regard

Comment: Several questions:  1 Since you have three values defining each Lat & Lon is this defining a location area or something else?  2. How do you want to compute distance as a vector, Manhattan distance or other?,  3.  What do you want to use as the start/end of the distance measurement?

Comment: @Suraj_enumales What have you tried? StackOverflow is not a coding serice. You have to show you made effort, post the code you have tried and errors/issues you are coming across.

Comment: @DavidErickson: I have put the code I tried in the post, which looks at close values by calculating the difference between lat, longs.

Comment: @suraj_enumalas Isn't Bakers the closest warehouse for all 3 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From the first dataframe, you can go through each row with `lambda x:` and compare to all rows of the second dataframe and return a list of the `absolute difference of latitude` and `add` that to the `absolute difference of longitude` using list comprehension. This effectively gives you the minimum distance.
2. Now, what you are interested in is the `index`, i.e. position of the minimum absolute difference of longiture plus absolute difference of latitude for each row. You can find this with `idxmin()`. In dataframe 1, this returns the index number which you can use to merge against the index of dataframe 2 to pull in the closest warehouse:

---

setup:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [-0.659901, -0.659786, -0.659821], 'long':[2.530561, 2.530797, 2.530587],
                      'd':[0.4202, 1.0957, 0.6309],
                      'o_lat':[-37.8095,-37.8030,-37.8050], 'o_long':[145.0000,145.0077,145.0024]})
data2= pd.DataFrame({'nearest_warehouse': ['Nickolson','Thompson','Bakers'], 
       'lat':[-37.818595, -37.812673, -37.809996], 'lon':[144.969551, 144.947069, 144.995232],
      'near_lat':[-37.8185,-37.8126,-37.8099], 'near_lon':[144.9695,144.9470,144.9952]})
```

code:

```
data1['key'] = data1.apply(lambda x: ((x['o_lat'] - data2['near_lat']).abs()
                                      + (x['o_long'] - data2['near_lon']).abs()).idxmin(), axis=1)
data1 = pd.merge(data1, data2[['nearest_warehouse']], how='left', left_on='key', right_index=True).drop('key', axis=1)
data1
Out[1]: 
        lat      long       d    o_lat    o_long nearest_warehouse
0 -0.659901  2.530561  0.4202 -37.8095  145.0000  Bakers          
1 -0.659786  2.530797  1.0957 -37.8030  145.0077  Bakers          
2 -0.659821  2.530587  0.6309 -37.8050  145.0024  Bakers
```

This result looks accurate if you append the two dataframes into one and do a basic scatterplot. As you can see `Bakers` warehouse is right there compared to the other points (graph IS to scale with last line of code):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'o_lat':[-37.8095,-37.8030,-37.8050], 'o_long':[145.0000,145.0077,145.0024],
                    'nearest_warehouse': ['0','1','2']})
data2= pd.DataFrame({'nearest_warehouse': ['Nickolson','Thompson','Bakers'],
      'o_lat':[-37.8185,-37.8126,-37.8099], 'o_long':[144.9695,144.9470,144.9952]})
df = data1.append(data2)

y = df['o_lat'].to_list()
z = df['o_long'].to_list()
n = df['nearest_warehouse'].to_list()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(z, y)

for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (z[i], y[i]))
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
```

[image]

Comment: @suraj_enumalas did this work for you? Kindly upvote and accept as solution if helpful. Thank you!